# How to add description to tvOS application

Tags: tvos, siri, corespotlight

I have a task to build a tvOS application that will pop up in search results through the new remote control using Siri. As I understand, Core Spotlight is not applicable to the current version of tvOS.

How do I expose the search keywords like in iOS searchable items?

Comment: Looking briefly at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CoreSpotlight_Framework/index.html), it looks like `CoreSpotlight` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Also check out [CoreSpotlight Changes for Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/CoreSpotlight.html) to see what has been changed from iOS to tvOS.

Comment: CoreSpotlight services are not applicable for tvOS sure I tried...